# Labels in XCode View, positioned differently in Simulator?

Tags: xcode, swift2, xcode7

In XCode 7, on a Swift 2 project, when I place a label onto the View, why is the label centred in XCode, but in the Simulator it's show off to the right?

This is just playing at the moment, where I don't want to play with constraints just yet (which I believe will be used later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when working through a demo, and this worked for me. Try using the 4.7 inch size view controller:

1. Look in the middle left hand menu (the Document Outline), if not shown it’s under Editor > Hide Document Outline (a misnomer, clicking it will Show or Hide it).
2. Click on the View Controller so it's highlighted.
3. Click on the 4th tab of the right hand one (Utilities: the Attributes Inspector). If not shown it’s under View > Utilities > Show Attributes Inspector.
4. Under Simulated Metrics is a Size option to change from “Inferred” to “iPhone 4.7-inch”.
5. You'll need to realign things again, but now these should look central in the View and in the Simulator.

Constraints, when you want to get to them, will probably be more helpful in this regard.